# vb.net arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow in decryption

Tags: vb.net, encryption

I am working on new decryption functions for password recovery tools. I tried code in c++ and worked:

```
void poco_pwd(u_char *pwd, int type) {
    int     len,
            tmp;
    u_char  *out;
    short   azz;

    if(type) azz = 0x2537;  // encrypt message
        else azz = 0x2a9a;  // other passwords

    len = strlen(pwd) >> 1;
    out = pwd;
    while(len--) {
        sscanf(pwd, "%02X", &tmp);
        pwd += 2;
        *out++ = tmp ^ (azz >> 8);
        azz = ((tmp + azz) * 0x8141) + 0x3171;
    }
    *out = 0;
}
```

I tried to convert this code to vb.net and c# but it throws arithmetic overflow operation. This functions new value is put to "azz" variable. "azz" is a short variable but this these values are very high. Strange is that it works in c++.

I converted this code to vb.net:

```
Dim encpass As String = "1EF66D8BD3C32476CEC8CF"
Dim encpassByte As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(HexToString(encpass))
Dim azz As Integer = &H2A9A
Dim len As Integer = encpassByte.Length >> 1
Dim storage(len) As Char

For i = 0 To len
    storage(i) = (ChrW(encpassByte(i) Xor (azz >> 8)))
    azz = ((encpassByte(i) + azz) * &H8141) + &H3171 //Error: arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.
Next

Console.WriteLine(storage.ToString)
Console.ReadKey()
```

Hex to string function:

```
Function HexToString(ByVal hex As String) As String
    Dim text As New System.Text.StringBuilder(hex.Length \ 2)
    For i As Integer = 0 To hex.Length - 2 Step 2
        text.Append(Chr(Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(i, 2), 16)))
    Next
    Return text.ToString
End Function
```

This code throws this error: **arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow**.

Comment: ["Schneier's Law"](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2011/04/schneiers_law.html): Anyone, from the most clueless amateur to the best cryptographer, can create an algorithm that he himself can't break. But this does not even seem to be encryption, just an encoding.

Comment: pwd += 2 isn't in the VB code nor is the logic for the sscanf. Seems like it was processing 2 chars at a time while the VB only do one.